# Why does Google Fonts add "rel=stylesheet" to its fonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts, google-fonts

I was considering adding `rel=preload` to my `<link>` tag in order to preload my site's main font, when I noticed that it already contained `rel="stylesheet"`:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

To my understanding, the `rel` attribute is used for identifying stylesheets, so why does Google use it for fonts? What advantage(s) does it offer?

Comment: The URL points to a stylesheet, not a font.

Comment: @Quentin ? It's a direct copy paste from the Google Fonts embed, this is how Google Fonts are loaded.

Comment: Copy and paste the URL into your browser's address bar. It's a stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you visit the link served by Google Fonts, you'll notice that it's actually a stylesheet.  When you import a font from a CDN, it's generally a stylesheet filled with [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) rules that define a new font from several source file URLs (generally WOFF, WOFF2, TTF, or OTF formats).  The same thing happens when you use `@import` to add fonts from an external source - it's importing a stylesheet, not just a font sourcefile.

Answer (score 1):

the attribute `rel` is to identify the relationship between the object and link you are trying to add. But `stylesheet` is the value specifying the styling nature of the link. Font is the style feature you try to alter in your original object.